# python pandas - Sub-string matching not working correctly

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 DFs
DFA & DFB

What I want to do is find a match between a string or a substring on the SKU column and merge the Company column to DFB

**Code**

```
// Remove white spaces, special characters and convert d type to string

    dfa['Clean SKU'] = dfa['SKU'].replace(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z ]', '', regex=True).replace("'", '')
    dfb['Clean SKU'] = dfb['SKU'].replace(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z ]', '', regex=True).replace("'", '')
    
    
    dfa['Clean SKU'] = dfa['Clean SKU'].replace(r'\s+', '', regex=True)
    dfb['Clean SKU'] = dfb['Clean SKU'].replace(r'\s+', '', regex=True)
    
    
    # Change D.Types
    dfa['Clean SKU'] = dfa['Clean SKU'].astype(str)
    dfb['Clean SKU'] = dfb['Clean SKU'].astype(str)

// Create new column to merge on and convert to lowercase
    dfa['SKU_to_merge'] = dfa['Clean SKU'].str.lower()


// Extract a unique list from the Clean SKU column
    pat = r'(%s)'%'|'.join(dfa['Clean SKU'].str.lower().unique())

// Create a column with common matches
    dfb['SKU_to_merge'] = dfb['Clean SKU'].str.lower().str.extract(pat)

// Merge the DFs on the SKU to merge
    dfb = dfb.merge(dfa[['SKU_to_merge','Company']], on='SKU_to_merge', how='left')
```

**ISSUE**
For SKU 601251x the SKU_to_merge should be 601251x as this SKU is in DFA (should only match by substring where direct matching is not possible). So in this instance the corresponding Company should be Google not Amazon

[image: a]

[image: b]

Comment: So basically you want to merge them based on 2 column?

Comment: @sogu no I want to merge based on one column, the SKU_to_Merge column in dfa and dfb

Comment: Please [do not post images of data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead. Otherwise people have to invest time to build them, instead of focusing on the answer.

Comment: @Timus I attempted to insert them as a table, as soon as I posted the question, the table lost it's format

Comment: `601251` comes before `601251x` in `pat`, so that won't work. You could try to use `dfb['Clean SKU'].sort_values(key=lambda c: -c.str.len())` instead of `dfb['Clean SKU']` when building `pat` (sorting by length, decending).

Comment: Re formatting: This happens when there are missing blank lines (before or after) the tables.

Comment: @Timus thank you, however I'm getting a **TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'**: this is what I'm doing, I tried to update pandas as I found this can cause an issue.  <pre>dfb['SKU_to_merge'] = dfb['Clean SKU'].sort_values(key=lambda c: -c.str.len()).str.lower().str.extract(pat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll skip the cleaning part, and assume the following state of the `df`s (before you start building `pat`):

`dfa`:

```
         SKU    Company  Clean SKU SKU_to_merge
0  3513420sz      Apple  3513420sz    3513420sz
1    rsz1052       Dell    rsz1052      rsz1052
2    smpx545  Microsoft    smpx545      smpx545
3     601251     Amazon     601251       601251
4    601251x     Google    601251x      601251x
```

`dfb`:

```
             SKU      Clean SKU
0  3513420sz2322  3513420sz2322
1    rsz1052dfff    rsz1052dfff
2  smpx545dffddd  smpx545dffddd
3        601251x        601251x
4         601251         601251
```

Then you could try

```py
pat = '(' + '|'.join(sorted(set(dfa['Clean SKU'].str.lower()), key=len, reverse=True)) + ')'
dfb['SKU_to_merge'] = dfb['Clean SKU'].str.lower().str.extract(pat)
dfb = dfb.merge(dfa[['SKU_to_merge','Company']], on='SKU_to_merge', how='left')
```

and should get the following `dfb`:

```
             SKU      Clean SKU SKU_to_merge    Company
0  3513420sz2322  3513420sz2322    3513420sz      Apple
1    rsz1052dfff    rsz1052dfff      rsz1052       Dell
2  smpx545dffddd  smpx545dffddd      smpx545  Microsoft
3        601251x        601251x      601251x     Google
4         601251         601251       601251     Amazon
```

The idea is to sort the parts of `pat` such that longer ones come first.

Answer (score 0):

## Similar Problem Solution

https://towardsdatascience.com/joining-dataframes-by-substring-match-with-python-pandas-8fcde5b03933

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame([  
          ['ABC', 'P1']
        , ['BCD', 'P2']
        , ['CDE', 'P3']
       ]
    ,columns = ['task_name', 'pipeline_name']
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([  
          ['RR', 'C1']
        , ['BC', 'C2']
        , ['HG', 'C3']
        , ['AB', 'C4']
       ]
    ,columns = ['partial_task_name', 'extra_value']
)

df1['join'] = 1
df2['join'] = 1

dfFull = df1.merge(df2, on='join').drop('join', axis=1)
df2.drop('join', axis=1, inplace=True)

dfFull['match'] = dfFull.apply(lambda x: x.task_name.find(x.partial_task_name), axis=1).ge(0)
dfResult = dfFull.groupby(["task_name", "pipeline_name"]).max().reset_index()[['task_name','pipeline_name','match']]

dfResult[~dfResult['match']][['task_name','pipeline_name']]
```